# Adding Seekbar in android homescreen widget

Tags: android, widget, seekbar, homescreen

How can I add a seekbar to mi homescreen widget? when I do it it says it cannot inflate, and I readed [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html) that you can only use progess bar not seekBar, Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry to say that - but you just can't.     android let's you use only minimal view types inside an AppWidget. I really don't understand why they did this limitation.
only thing you can do about it is to modify and customize one of the views that appWidget allows (such progress bar) by creating your own class extending the origin view, and change/add behavior and look, then in the appWidget xml layout file - use this custom view. in this why you can manipulate android appWidget limitations to show your derived custom view.

Comment: In the latest N release, do we have seek bar in widget or not ?

Comment: I don't know.. but you can check in the documentation

Answer (score 1):

`SeekBar` is not supported in app widgets, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a SeekBar but you can use a ProgressBar. Don't know about your case but for me was enough.